# How to select parent div in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to select a parent div in Google Earth which doesn't have any id or class and it is just a div element.  I used this method:

```
div < div.well {background-color: red !important; }
```

since the div contains another div with the class of `.well` but this seems not to work. What am I doing wrong?

### Update

See this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/apt6h/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know the context here, but if you can't modify the html, this is possible with jQuery as follows:

```
<script>
jQuery('div.well').parent('div').css('background', 'red');
</script>
```

As others have noted, there is no CSS solution.

Comment: The OP wants a CSS solution, not a jQuery one.

Comment: There is no css solution to 'select a parent div'

Answer (score 1):

As of now there's no construct in CSS to select parent elements. For more info on the subject, check this:

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/114029)

Comment: Hi Thanks for comment but take a look at this link http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: @MonaCoder It says: "there are no parent selectors in CSS"

Comment: Please look at @Esteban example http://jsbin.com/aaddj/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @MonaCoder Yeah... but that's different. With `>` you're selecting a descendant.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately CSS does not give us a way to select parents. You can select it as a descendant of it's own parents thought. Maybe provide some more context or some source code so we can help more.

Comment: Hi Gabriel I updated the code on the jsfidle now

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<div>First div.
<div><div class="well">Second</div>
<div>Third
```

CSS

```
div > div.well { background: red; }
```

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/aaddj/1/edit?html,css,output.

EDIT: before complaining/editing about the syntax, watch this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxmcDoAxdoY. The html5 parser is smarter than us.

EDIT2: Here is a fiddle forked from OP's working: http://jsfiddle.net/MEhUj/.

Comment: Thanks Esteban but this is not working on my example! can you please take alook at updated jsfiddle?

Comment: Have you noticed the `>` instead of `<`? `div < div.well {background-color: red !important; }` should be `div > div.well {background-color: red !important; }`.

Comment: but how come it is not grabbing that div (the white one around well?

Comment: It **only** selects the div tags containing another `div` with the `well` class.

Comment: The HTML5 parser parses HTML5, not CSS. Just FYI. Unless you were referring to the lack of a doctype or html/head/body tags and not the incorrect CSS syntax, in which case you really need a doctype for most things.

Comment: I was pointing out, because people like to complain about a lot, its faster to write to answer a question, since i dont have that much time. I **know** what the parser do, and i believe that html5 will place the doctype there if you missed it.

Comment: My answer works, so there is no need for a downvote :)

Comment: "i believe that html5 will place the doctype there if you missed it" No. The whole point of a doctype is that you need to declare it yourself. Also, since you said yourself that you're using `>`, what makes you so sure you're selecting the parent and not the child? I don't see why you need to be so smug either.